# Extension of a Linear Transformation

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed linear space and $Y$ be a subspace of $X$. Let $f : Y \rightarrow  Z$ be a continuous linear map where $Z$ is finite dimensional.

Then how can I show that there exists a continuous linear map $g : X \rightarrow Z$ that extends $f$?

I was trying to use Hahn Banach Theorem, but cannot reach the conclusion.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose a system of coordinates $(e_1, \ldots , e_n)$ for $Z$ : then your map $f$ is of the form 
$$f(y)=\sum_i \phi_i(y) e_i$$
where the $\phi_i$ are continuous linear forms. By Hahn-Banach, you can extend those to continuous linear forms $\psi_i$ on $X$, and the function 
$$\hat{f}(z)=\sum_i \psi_i(z) e_i$$
is a continuous linear extension of $f$.

Comment: How are you getting f to be of the above form?

Comment: let $z = f(y)$ arbitrary : since the $e_i$ form a basis of $Z$, then $z= \sum_i \alpha_i e_i$. it is straightforward to check that the maps $z \mapsto \alpha_i$ are linear and continuous. those are what I called $\phi_i$

Comment: They are linear forms on Z , right.So how can they act on Y?

Comment: nope, they are linear forms on $Y$... try with an example

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant $\phi_i : y \mapsto \alpha_i$.
In other words, $\phi_i = e_i^* \circ f$

Comment: More general, by basically the same argument, you can extend maps with codomain $l_\infty$.